# Why does my torrent client hangs when I use USB tethering?

Tags: tethering, qbittorrent

I have an Internet connection via LAN. But it provides limited speed. So I usually connect my phone to get better speed. I use qBittorrent. So now whenever I enable USB tethering, this client starts hanging and stops responding. I thought that the problem was because two internet connections at once. But when I removed the LAN cable it still didn't respond. Only when I remove my phone, that it starts working. What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: What if you disable the LAN and connect and start the tethered connection BEFORE loading up the torrent program?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and I found an issue opened on github (linked below) and using that, I followed these steps and it worked for me.

First disable USB tethering.

Next In qBittorrent settings:

1. Change the network interface setting to anything but "any".
2. Turn off UPnP and NAT-PMP (under Connection).
3. Set the global maximum connections to 10 (if currently greater then 10).
4. Also reduce the connections per torrent (I set it to 10).
5. Then go to advanced settings and lower the half-open ports limit. (eg 5) (some value less than 10).

Now close qBittorrent, enable tethering, open qBittorrent, and set the network interface setting to the USB tethered connection. Your torrents should start downloading now.

Source: [qBittorrent github](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/issues/1764/)